# Strange problem with Email::MIME - can't use string as a HASH ref

Tags: perl

I'm having a strange problem with Email:MIME. I have the following code, which is intended to parse a MIME email message piped to it:

```
my $parsed = Email::MIME->new(<STDIN>);
print $parsed->body;
```

When I run this, either by piping a sample MIME email into it, or by setting my host to pipe new email to it and sending myself one, I get the following error on the first line:

```
> Can't use string ("Received: from
> servera02.tk2adsm") as a HASH ref
> while "strict refs" in use at
> /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Email/Simple.pm
> line 100, <STDIN> line 71.
```

The line shown in the error varies according to the email but it is always the second line of the email content (so I'm really not very sure why it's claiming it's STDIN line 71). I've done some googling about this and it really seems to be unique to me - does anyone have any ideas?

I'm not a Perl expert by a long way, and I've never used Email::MIME, so I'm hoping this is something simple.

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email%3a%3aMIME) says that `new()` expects its argument to be a message in the form of a string. `<STDIN>` is an array (since an argument list is in list context).

Try converting the message to a string as you pass it: `my $parsed = Email::MIME->new(join('', <STDIN>));`

Comment: The `new` method is actually documented in the base class, [Email::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Simple).

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I have to say I didn't realise <STDIN> was an array. Not sure whether I love or hate this loosly-typed stuff. :)

Comment: Chris R: no, <> is an operator; like many perl operators it behaves differently in list context vs scalar context.

Answer (score -1):

i mean you might not get the error if you turn off strict refs

Comment: True, you wouldn't get this error if strict refs were off (in the module, which you don't control).  Instead, your program would just not work properly for no obvious reason.